# MVC noob question: How can I get the value from a textbox or dropdown from my view from within its controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It's potentially long enough that I cannot pass it in on the query string. Is it possible to submit the entire form? If so, how would I retrieve the form's values in the controller?

Answer (score 2):

To clarify mpminnich's response, you can accept a [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx) as an action parameter:

```
public ActionResult Add(FormCollectiom form) {
    var foo = form["fieldName"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess a visual would have been much better. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The FormCollection will have all the values that are on the view form. You can search the collection by index or control name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use `method="POST"` on your form and this way all values will be sent along the POST body and not in the query string. Example:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    ... some input fields
<% } %>
```

And in your controller action you could either use a strongly typed view model to fetch those values back thanks to the default model binder (recommended):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

or fetch them from the request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var param1 = Request["param1"];
    var param2 = Request["param2"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with accessing the `Request[]` object, but I believe accepting a [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx) as an action parameter is more inline with MVC's best practices.